# Bash: Is it possible to declare each list item on a new line?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Example: You normally list values
in a shell `for` command in a horizontal layout:

```bsh
for var in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do
  echo $var
done
```

It would be nice, for version control and readability purposes,
to enter each list item on its own line. Is this possible?

You can't do the following, with or without `\r\n`:

```bsh
for var in 
  0 
  1 
  2 
  3 
  4 
  5 
  6  
  7 
  8 
  9
do
  echo $var
done
```

Interestingly enough, this *almost* works
(same regardless of single or double quote):

```bsh
for var in 
 '0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9'
do
   echo $var
done
```

outputting:

```
-bash: demo.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token ` '0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9''
  -bash: demo.sh: line 11: `  9''
```

This does *not* work, regardless of single or double quote.

```bsh
for var in 
  "0"
  "1"
  "2"
  "3"
  "4"
  "5"
  "6"
  "7"
  "8"
  "9"
do
   echo $var
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to this tested version:

```
#!/bin/bash --
for var in  \
1 \
2 \
3 \
4 \
6 \
 ; do
  printf "%s\n" "${var}"
done
```

the `for` loop splits by default a string containing  (spaces) and `\n` into separate elements.

`'` used in your `for` loop instructs the shell (in your version) to consider the parameter as one single value, a string containing several lines.

The test:

```
$ ./list.sh
1
2
3
4
6
```

The first version for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash --
listint='
1
2
3
4
6
'

for var in ${listint} ; do
  printf "%s\n" "${var}"
done
```

The `'` enable to define string over multiple lines, including the `\n`.

Comment: Hey hey, that worked! Can you elaborate a bit on what's happening to enable this?

Comment: @KevinSuttle the example at the top had been updated with something very close to your version.

Comment: FYI: I have added an answer that implicitly identifies disadvantages of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an approach that combines
aspects of the parts of [Jay jargot’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1064698/150988#1064703):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
data=(
        "too hot"       # Papa bear
        "too cold"      # Mama bear

        "just right"    # Baby bear
)

for var in "${data[@]}"
do
        printf "%s\n" "$var"
done
```

This creates a data array.

This has the following advantages:

- You can put comments on the data.
- You can put blank lines in the data. 
  (You can sort-of do that with the first part of Jay’s answer,
  but it has to be a `\`, not an actual blank line. 
  You can do it directly with the second part of Jay’s answer.)
- You can have values with spaces in them. 
  (You can do that with the first part of Jay’s answer, but not the second part.)
- You can use the data multiple times
  (i.e., you can have multiple `for var in "${data[@]}"` loops in the script,
  without having to repeat the data). 
  (You can do that with the second part of Jay’s answer,
  but not the first part.)
- You can add spaces at the ends of lines. 
  (If you add a space after a backslash in the first part of Jay’s answer,
  it will fail, and the reason might be hard to debug.)

Disadvantages of my answer:

- It doesn’t work in all shells. 
  (It does work in bash, ksh, and probably some others.)
- The `"${data[@]}"` syntax is tricky and hard to remember.